# Bash string range and replace

Tags: bash, sed, variable, replace

To print part of the string, replace `,` with `.` I use command:

```
echo "${q:16:6}" | sed 's/,/./'
```

Is it possible to use something like:

```
echo "${q:16:6/,/.}"
```

because it does not work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't stack/nest parameter expansion in Bash, so not even

```
echo "${${q:16:6}/,/.}"
```

will work. (Nested expansions like that *do* work in Zsh, though.)

If you want to stay within Bash, you'll need to use a temporary variable:

```
foo="${q:16:6}"
echo "${foo/,/.}"
```