# Two replacements in one go

Tags: shell-script, shell, posix, replace

How do I go about replacing one character for another and then another character for another in one line and printing the result?

As an example, consider the following code:

```
string="1 33 4 a"
echo ${string// /_} #prints 1_33_4_a
```

Now, I'd like to replace back underscores for spaces so I tried:

```
echo ${${string// /_}//_/ }
```

But this yields the error "bad substitution".

I know how to do it with variable assignment, I do not want that. I want do it in just one line, without using `sed` and as portable as possible.

This is just a challenge to myself which will hopefully be instructive.

Comment: Switch to `zsh` and you'll be able to nest parameter expansions...

Comment: In `bash` you can't, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486745/bash-string-range-and-replace/486746

Comment: @nohillside Would you care to either close as duplicate or give an answer?

Comment: nothing change in string so I think echo $string is enough.

Comment: @2r3plac3 why do you care that much about your question being closed? Why don't you delete it yourself? There's no answer to it, so I don't see how that 'this question has already an answer here' boilerplate would help anybody ;-)

Comment: @mosvy I am unable to delete the question, there's no button for it. And I want to help keep the site clean. In addition to his, I asked this question in incognito mode, so once I close the browser, it's out of my control to accept an answer.